# Why does Craster give those sacrifices to the White Walkers?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game Of Thrones Season 4, the wildling Craster leaves his sons, from his wives (at the same time his daughters), into the woods to be taken by the White Walkers' king, after that he turned them into new White Walkers. I tried to figure out the reason behind this event, but no clues.

So, What is the story behind this action? And why does the White Walkers' king need those new born babies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to *Faizan*'s answer of giving them as sacrifices to be spared by the White Walkers, you also have to consider that Craster was sleeping with his own daughters, likely for his enjoyment (and less for theirs) and they were also doing all their work for him. So new daughters simply mean more workers and more "company", while a son is not really of use to him. And it is clear that Craster isn't really a man to shed tears for his dying kin.

Rather on the contrary, a son could actually be a danger to him if he grows up and decides to revolt against his father's cruelty to his sisters. Craster has conditioned his daughters into obedience to him (and even more so in a medieval world where women were even less likely to revolt against their patriarch, even if they actually would have been able to do so in unison). A son might be harder to keep "under control" and as said, wouldn't have any use for Craster, since he doesn't really need a fighter, due to his arrangement with the Crows. It would merely mean a disruptance to the nice little life he's built himself there.

So I think even without the White Walkers a son probably wouldn't have a long life at Craster's Keep.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, i agree with you, but what if he is giving them to the White Walkers, whome happen that lot of them are in reality Craster's sons, without mentionning this fact of fearing them

Comment: @Mourad But they don't know who Craster is, nor that they are his sons. They merely White Walkers and no humans anymore.

Comment: may be but in Game Of Thrones any thing could happen

Comment: @NapoleonWilson +1 for sharing all the details. :-)

Answer (score 5):

It was an agreement between White Walkers and Craster, that he and his family will not be bothered by White Walkers, if he agrees to sacrifice newly born sons. White Walkers needed his newly born sons to convert them and grow their army.

Comment: Is there canon for this idea, or is it speculation?

Comment: As far as I remember two Night's Watch men discuss Craster and all the incestuous relationship he maintains has a reason. As audience we can guess the obvious reason and all the details that Napoleon shared.

Comment: Craster should have been king of the seven kingdoms if his ability to build diplomatic relationships is that elite.  Everybody else can barely get a word out before they get a sword to the throat and Craster is somehow managing round-table negotiation sessions.

Comment: It *is* pretty weird situation, but it does appear to be the case. Seems Walkers could be more reasonable before the winter came. Seems it was more of an *unsaid* agreement, though.